# How should be a typical workflow of OAuth in Angular2?

Tags: angular, oauth, oauth-2.0

I already implemented OAuth2 in my **backend** server and it's already working. When I enter the url `/api/oauth/github` I get my Github profile once I log in and then I store this data in a database.

Although, Angular is not based on routes and requests and I'm not sure how I should redirect the user to the Github login page and how to get data back from my backend server which has the Github profile saved in the database.

Do I create a `<a>` tag with `href` set to my `/api/oauth/github`? But what about after I get redirected to my backend (because of Github callback url)? Should I redirect again to my angular url? and how to send this github profile data back to my angular app?